# Moving between multiple HTAs

Tags: hta

The scenario...

HTA #1 is launched, which displays a window with three button choices.

```
[Process]    [Postpone]    [Exit]
```

If the Process button is clicked, HTA #1 is closed, a process is started in the background, and HTA #2 is launched, which displays a window with further information that remains open as long as the process is running. Once the process has completed, HTA #2 is closed and HTA #3 is launched, which displays a window with further information and a single [Exit] button. Once the Exit button is clicked, HTA #3 is closed and that's it.

If Postpone is clicked, HTA #4 is launched, which displays a window with further information and a single button to ask the user to verify their choice. Once the user clicks the button, HTA #4 is closed and that's it.

If Exit is clicked, no new windows are launched, HTA #1 is closed and that's it.

I have each of the individual HTAs complete, but just can't figure out how to move between them.

Is this possible? If so, how? If not, is there an easier way to accomplish this?

Comment: Ok, might be an obvious question but an HTA is basically a local web page with enhanced privileges so why not just use overlay `div` to display extra content or hyperlinks to navigate around instead of wanting to add extra layers of complexity? You could do the whole thing using callbacks in one page or multiple pages, instead of breaking it into separate HTAs.

Comment: Create an instance of `WScript.Shell` (ActiveX object), and use its [Run](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5fk67ky(v=vs.84).aspx)  method to open new HTAs. `window.close()` will do, when you want to close a HTA window.